# How to Matching conditions in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am having dataframe which looks like:

```
Count_ID      Stats        Date
123           A            10-01-2017
123           A            12-01-2017
123           B            15-01-2017
456           B            18-01-2017
456           C            17-01-2017
789           A            20-01-2017
486           A            25-01-2017
486           A            28-01-2017
```

I want to add a Status & Count column in Dataframe which give me below mention status.

- Match oldest `Count_ID` as per date having `Stats` as "A" compare if any `Count_ID` with same value (i.e 123) is having date > than that Previous same `Count_ID` having `Stats` as "A", than show it "False" in status column.
- If there are multiple `Count_ID` with same value (i.e 123) than check `Stats` "A" than match any same `Count_ID` with `Stats` other than "A" or "A" are having date > than of those having `Stats` "A", than show status as "False"
- If there are multiple same `Count_ID` (i.e 123) having `Stats` as "A" with date difference <30 days (w.r.t the previous `Count_ID` as per Date) show status as "False-B".
- In count column, show difference of days between same `Count_ID` created from previous `Count_ID`.
- Where no condition show it as "-".

Required Output:

```
Count_ID      Stats        Date        Status     Count
123           A            10-01-2017  False-B    0
123           A            12-01-2017  False-B    2
123           B            15-01-2017  False      3
456           B            18-01-2017  -          0
456           C            17-01-2017  False      1
789           A            20-01-2017  -          0
486           A            25-01-2017  False-B    0
486           A            28-01-2017  False-B    3
```

Dput:

```
structure(list(Count_ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 456L, 456L, 789L, 
486L, 486L), Stats = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A"
), Date = c("10/01/2017", "12/01/2017", "15/01/2017", "18/01/2017", 
"17/01/2017", "20/01/2017", "25/01/2017", "28/01/2017")), .Names = c("Count_ID", 
"Stats", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Comment: could you provide your example data with `dput(my_data)` please. This makes it more handy to work on your problem.

Comment: @drmariod I have a very big dataframe `dput` is not possible.

Comment: what about `dput(head(my_data, 15))`?

Comment: @drmariod Updated the `dput`

Comment: @drmariod Did you check dput data??

Comment: I don't quite understand your conditions (they're very complicated and nested), but I can maybe point you in a helpful direction: Try the `dplyr` functions `group_by()`, `arrange()`, and `last()`. The idea is that maybe if you group the data by Count_ID and Date and then sorted it by Date, then `last` could mark the last entry in that group for you.

Comment: @DuckPyjamas I have tried but couldn't succeed yet, where you didn't understand the condition??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly then you can try this

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Count_ID) %>%
  mutate(Count = c(0, abs(as.numeric(diff(Date)))),
         Status = ifelse((Date==min(Date[Stats=='A']) | Date>min(Date[Stats=='A'])) & (n()>1), "FALSE", "-")) %>%
  mutate(Status = ifelse(Stats=='A' & Count < 30 & Status=='FALSE', 'FALSE-B', Status)) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Note that the condition for "row item 5" is not clear so I have left it as `-`. I am not sure how you want to go about this row as there is no `Stats = A` for `Count_ID = 456`.

**Output is:**

```
  Count_ID Stats       Date Count  Status
1      123     A 2017-01-10     0 FALSE-B
2      123     A 2017-01-12     2 FALSE-B
3      123     B 2017-01-15     3   FALSE
4      456     B 2017-01-18     0       -
5      456     C 2017-01-17     1       -
6      789     A 2017-01-20     0       -
7      486     A 2017-01-25     0 FALSE-B
8      486     A 2017-01-28     3 FALSE-B
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Count_ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 456L, 456L, 789L, 
486L, 486L), Stats = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A"
), Date = structure(c(17176, 17178, 17181, 17184, 17183, 17186, 
17191, 17194), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Count_ID", "Stats", 
"Date"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```